# Eventos de touch swipe,swipeRight e Left não funcionam no android 4.4.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, apache-cordova, jquery-mobile

Os eventos de touch não funcionam no Android 4.4.2 alguém saberia como resolver isso?

Comment: Como tive muitos negativos na resposta, coloquei uma recompensa p/ quem negativou, ter a oportunidade de dar uma resposta melhor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que é realmente um bug com a versão do Android.

Por enquanto só podemos esperar.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1729

https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/issues/823

Comment: Verdade já tinha visto esses links, porem pensei que alguem saberia algum  jeito de "Burlar" isso. Mas obrigado vou tentar  ver alguma outra forma de fazer o que necessito com meu app :)